# The use of present perfect and present perfect continuous for finished actions

Tags: present-tense

These sentences are written by native speakers. I have noticed that native speakers use present perfect continuous and present perfect even if the action is no longer in process,  but do they use them  when the action has  finished the same day or a few days ago only? Because in these examples it's either "a few days ago" or "last week" if it's more than that would it be wrong to use present perfect and present perfect continuous? I mean if it was "last month" instead of "last week"  "a few months" or "a few weeks ago" instead of "a few days ago".

1."I have been living/I have lived  in the same house for twenty years" (I don't live in that house now.)

2."I have been living/I have lived in that house for 20 years". ( I moved a few days ago.)

3. "She's been studying/has studied English for two years, but last week she moved to another school where they don't teach it."
4. "My English classes are from 8am to 5pm. It's my last class today. I have been studying/have studied English for two years. On the same day up until 5 pm present perfect and present perfect continuous are used after 5 pm they are correct too, but past simple can also be used.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use either tense when speaking of a house I had moved out of; certainly not if it was a week or more ago. But I think you have asked about this before.

Comment: Some native speakers use  present perfect and present perfect continuous but only if it was a week ago. But if it was a few weeks or months ago native speakers would use past simple not present perfect or present perfect continuous. Right? In this context.

Comment: "I lived in that house for twenty years". Yes.